# Single selection and fire selecion of AbstractGraphicalEditPart

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef

I Have an `AbstractDecoratedTextEditor` and it has a tab with components of `AbstractGraphicalEditPart`.

I want to

1) Select single components. If I select one component, other componentes was unselected

2) When I select one component, I wan to to fire the selection listenner of eclipse. Because this listenner will change the properties view of Eclipse.

I tried this code for number 2, but not work.

```
((IFigure) componentFigure).addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        ComponentEditPart.this.setSelected(SELECTED);
        fireSelectionChanged();
        super.mousePressed(arg0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a selection listener in GEF, but it's on the EditPartViewer. Add a ISelectionChangedListener to your Graphical viewer. Each editpart has a method #getViewer() (i.e. AbstractGraphicalEditPart#getViewer()).

```
graphicalEditPart.getViewer().addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
// TODO: implement it to handle selection change
}
}};
```

Comment: getViewer() is null on my AbstractGraphicalEditPart constructor...
And I think that I need an Listenner on IFigure component...
I needo to select an IFigure and change the property

Comment: Why is the viewer null? You are probably missing the RootEditPart in your implementation. I'd suggest to fix that and then use the already available mechanism in GEF to track selection... Other good things will come with the RootEditPart such as separation of figures into various layers, scaling etc.